# Trash icon on Desktop but not listed from terminal command "ls -all"

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, trash

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and on my Desktop there is the Trash icon.

When I use terminal to list the contents of the Desktop I do not see anything related to Trash. I was expecting ".desktop" file such as Trash.desktop, but there is none.

Why is that?

Comment: You won't see a `.desktop` file listed it's not there!

Answer (score 2):

There is no `.desktop` file for Trash in your `~/Desktop/` directory. The trash icon is a *feature* provided by GNOME shell and/or Nautilus, it's probably hard-coded somewhere.

You can enable/disable this feature using `gsettings`/`dconf`. Run the following to hide the trash icon from your desktop

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.desktop trash-icon-visible false
```